# Acknowledge request has been received to the user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to send a acknowledgement to the user that request has been received and `FUNCTION_NAME` has been called. The `FUNCTION_NAME` internally calls other functions and takes about 10-15 mins to complete. So the user is acknowledged that his request is captured for processing. Any hints/leads towards handing this approaching

```
import os
import json
import boto3
import json as js
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    res=lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='FUNCTION_NAME',InvocationType='RequestResponse',Payload=js.dumps(event))
    res=res['Payload'].read().decode()
    data= js.loads(res)['body']
    status=js.loads(res)['statusCode']
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded':"false",
        'statusCode': status,
        'body': data
    }
```

Comment: Not sure but does it help you? invoke_async: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke_async
and what the reason to import json twice?

Comment: @BrownBear importing json twice is typo, since I am trying various approaches

Comment: and other option is change the parameter InvocationType='Event'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the boto3 documentation, you can invoke the other lambda synchronously or asynchronously.

To invoke the lambda asynchronously, change the `InvocationType` to `Event`.

See the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) for reference.

Please do not use `invoke_async`, this is deprecated.